# Accessing synthetic fields

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Is there a way to access a synthetic view field if it is shadowed?

I have a fragment A and B, which inherit from C. They have some similar UI code. So in C I defined a `abstract val` view fields, which values must be provided from A and B. But these fields shadow `kotlin synthetic` fields and  I cannot do something like this

```
override val input: EditText
    get() = synthetic.input
```

Is there a way to do what I want without field renaming?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data binding instead of synthetic view field, enable data binding in your project and then you can access views without synthetic view field or find viewbyid

here is a reference for [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/)

Comment: Whole project is built on `kotlin-android-extensions`, I don't won't to import a library for couple of screens. But I agree, that data binding, or butterknife, or something else will work in my case.

Comment: It's not a library just enable databinding  in android section in your gradle 

  dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }